# Create dictionary from mysql AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql-python

Trying to create a dictionary from a mysql database using two columns and then assign it a variable keep getting the traceback `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'name'`.

```
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.execute("select server_id, name from servers")

dict = {}
for row in cursor:
    dict[row.server_id] = row.name

    print(dict)
```

Comment: I'd advise from not naming variables after reserved words in python such as `dict=...` as it risks overwriting functionality and ending up with very spooky results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows are *tuples*, not objects with named attributes per column. In your case, `name` is the value at index `1`, the `server_id` the value at index `0`:

```
d = {}
for row in cursor:
    d[row[0]] = row[1]

print(d)
```

You could make this easier on yourself by using tuple assignments:

```
d = {}
for server_id, name in cursor:
    d[server_id] = name

print(d)
```

However, because you want to use the first element as the key, and the second as the value, you could make this even simpler and just pass the cursor directly to a `dict()` call:

```
d = dict(cursor)
```

This pulls in each `(server_id, name)` tuple and turns it into a key and value pair in a new dictionary.

Note that I deliberately used the name `d` for the dictionary in the above examples. Had I used `dict` instead, then we couldn't use `dict(cursor)` anymore!

Answer (score 0):

`row` in your case is tuple `(server_id, name)`, that's why calling `row.name` won't work - tuples don't support named attributes. Try `row[0]` and `row[1]` instead or unpack tuple:

```
d = {}
for row in cursor:
    server_id, name = row
    d[server_id] = name

print(d)
```